# How to find average of column when certain condition is met

Tags: r

I am new to R and am working with a data set with multiple columns but the ones I’m working with are
“member_casual” and one that I made with

```
trip_data <- trip_data %>% 
  mutate(trip_duration = (ended_at - started_at))

trip_data <- trip_data %>% 
  mutate(trip_duration_min = (trip_duration/60))
```

I converted them from diff time  to numeric

```
trip_data$trip_duration_min <- as.numeric(as.character(trip_data$trip_duration_min))
```

But i am trying to find the average trip_duration_min when for both members and casuals I tried this

```
trip_data %>% 
  select(trip_data, member_casual)
  filter(member_casual = 'member') %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(trip_duration_min)
```

When I run

```
sapply(trip_data, class)
```

it says it numeric but I get an error saying “must subset columns with valid subscript vector.  has the wrong type ‘data.frame<“
I am stuck and any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please include in your question the output of `dput(trip_data)` or `dput(head(trip_data))` so we can understand what the data looks like.

Comment: Perhaps you want `group_by(member_casual) %>%` instead of `filter(member_casual = 'member') %>% `

Comment: I guess the problem is in the `select()` statement. Is `trip_data` a column of the dataframe `trip_data`? Further, you are trying to summarize the column `trip_duration_min`, but you have only selected the columns `trip_data` (if it exists) and `member_casual`, so you do not have the column `trip_duration_min´when you get to the `summarize()`. Your best bet is probably to remove the `select()` statement.